# How do I pass a value from an HTML tag to Vue's data object on each iteration of a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of users and I have ordered them by title. When the list if created I want to check if the previous user has a different title than the current user and if so do some logic.

````
      <div>

        <div v-for="user in the_category`.`users" :key="user.id">

           <h1 v-bind:title="user.title"  >{{ user.title  }}</h1>

        // If the title is not the same as the previous user.title I would like the following <h3> below to show
        // However if the title is the same as the previous user.title I do not want it to show.
        // How do I pass the value/text of the <h1> to my title data variable
        // and compare the value with the last value on each loop? 


          <h3 v-show="user.title != title">This is a new title</h3> 

        </div>

        </div>
      </template>

      <script>
      export default {
        props: [
          "the_category",
          "title"

          ],

        data: function() {
          return {
              category: this.the_category,
              title: "",    
          };
        },
         }
         </script>
        ```
````

Comment: You can get the index of your loop and then check the initial array with the index minus one. use `v-for="(item, index) in items"`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I do not fully grasp what you are saying. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I wrote a full answer, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of your loop in your `v-for` and then use it to check the full array.

First, replace this:

```
v-for="user in the_category`.`users"
```

With this:

```
v-for="(user, index) in the_category`.`users"
```

That will get both the current element (`user`) and its index in the array (`index`).

Then, replace this:

```
<h3 v-show="user.title != title">This is a new title</h3>
```

With this:

```
<h3 v-show="index === 0 || user.title != the_category`.`users[index - 1].title">This is a new title</h3>
```

Your `<h3>` will then be visible if your element is the first (`index === 0`) or if the current title differs from the previous.

Comment: I changed my code according to your example and now the "<h3>This is a new title</h3>" displays after the title regardless of being the same or not. I have 25 users and 3 different titles. all users have one of the three titles. The "<h3>This is a new title</h3>" appears 25 times now.

Comment: @Elcapeetan are your users ordered by title?

Comment: yes they are ordered by title, then name using lodash's return orderBy(this.category.users, ['title', 'name'])

Comment: <h3 v-if="index === 0 || user.title != the_category.users[index - 1]">This is a new title</h3> returned the same results.

Comment: @Elcapeetan my bad, replace `the_category.users[index - 1]` with `the_category.users[index - 1].title` and it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Ayrton